# nodejs export variable from function

Tags: node.js

I want to export variable 'result_array' from './models/devices-client.js' below

```
var config = require('./config');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(config.dbadmin_uri, function (err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
// console.log('Successfully connected');
var collection = db.collection('repvpn2');
collection.find().toArray(function (err, result_array) {
// console.log('Found results:', result_array);
    module.exports.Hosts = result_array;
    db.close();
    });
});
```

but when import in the other file it prints 'undefined' ?

```
var Hosts = require('./models/devices-client').Hosts;
console.log(Hosts);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: `MongoClient.connect()` is asynchronous; in other words, it may take a (short) while before it is finished and calls the callback function that sets `module.exports.Hosts`. Until that time, for instance right after calling `require()`, that export will be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let your module take an async function callback.

```
// JavaScript source code
var config = require('./config');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
module.exports = function (callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(config.dbadmin_uri, function (err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log('Successfully connected');
        var collection = db.collection('repvpn2');
        collection.find().toArray(function (err, result_array) {
            // console.log('Found results:', result_array);
            callback(err, result_array);
            db.close();
        });
    });
}
```

---

```
require('./models/devices-client')(function callback(err,Hosts) {
   //Hosts Here
});
```

Comment: $ node repcert.js 

    /home/irek/repvpn/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:97
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^
    ReferenceError: results_array is not defined at      /home/irek/repvpn/models/devices-client.js

Comment: Typo, `result_array` not `results_array`. sry